# Calling an API With useEffect . when Trying to mapping user it is saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ajax

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import User from './components/User/User';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create an scoped async function in the hook
    async function loadData() {
      const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data.results);
    }

    loadData()
  }, [])

  console.log(user)

  return (
    

    
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
          {

            user && user.results.map(usr => <User user={usr}></User>)
          }
      </ul>
     
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am Calling the API with useEffect. Before that I have set a const with useState named user with a default value of empty array. In useEffect I set user value with setUSer(). But when I am mapping user it is giving mean error with a message TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ;

Answer (score 2):

Seems unlikely that you’d need both `setUser(data.results)` and `user.results.map` - that’s like `data.results.results.map`. I think you want `user.map`, and then you can drop the `user &&` check too, because `.map` will still work on the empty array.

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
Showing this after doing that..

Comment: Could that come from the `User` component?

Answer (score 0):

put a conditional rendering for the results. this happens because the api fetch takes time and until then ur `user` variable is undefined.

Comment: How i will do that conditional rendering?

Comment: `{user.length == 0 ? null : user.results.map(usr => <User user={usr}></User>)}`

Answer (score 0):

If you check empty array as "user &&", it'll still give true.

Try to check `user.length > 0` or `isEmpty(user)` from lodash/underscore.

```
user.length > 0 && user.results && user.results.map(usr => <User user={usr}></User>)
```

Answer (score 0):

### as you can see , your fetching an api with Array Name : results .
this is the link :- https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10
so your setting the user to be the data.results .
and then accessing user.results.map , and thats wrong because you dont have results in user , the user values equal to results.values

solution :-
1- change from user.results.map to -> user.map
here how it will be :-

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import User from './components/User/User';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create an scoped async function in the hook
    async function loadData() {
      const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data.results);
    }

    loadData()
  }, [])

  console.log(user)

  return (
    

    
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
          {

            user && user.map(usr => <User user={usr}></User>)
          }
      </ul>
```